# How can I test the menus in a GUI using ruby?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, automated-tests

I am trying to test a GUI using the Win32API through ruby.  I would like to test that the menus in the GUI are working correctly, but GetMenu returns 0, indicating (as I understand it) that GUI (written in MATLAB) is not using the basic Win32API menus.  I would like to avoid having to simulate mouse clicks at specific locations to select the menu if I can, and instead just call the menu automatically through the test.  Does anyone know what function/API I need to use for this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start with [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294%28VS.85%29.aspx). It's not pretty though, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Does the menu use shortcuts (e.g. Alt-F,O for "open")?  If so, maybe you could just send those instead of simulating mouse clicks.